# How to increment +1 from timestamp every 10.6 seconds

Tags: php, javascript, time, increment

I am configuring a site for a dog rescue organization.
I an trying to create a euthanasia counter to visually indicate how many dogs are being put down in the U.S. on a daily basis. 
A live "death counter" that uses current time so, it remains counting non-stop page to page for the visitor.

I want the counter to start at 0 every day at midnight.
Then, I want the counter to increment by +1 every 10.6 seconds.

What I have come up with is a hack at best and seemingly not accurate.

My EMBARRASSING code is below and I know math is wrong but, I am at my limit of understanding.
Also my lack of understanding strtotime has prob added unnecessary lines.

```
        <?php
    $tsdate = date('d-m-Y');
    $date = date('m/d/Y');
    $timestamp = strtotime($tsdate);
    ?>
    <b><font color="#ff0000">
<span id="number"><?=(int)((time()-$timestamp)/14.6);?></span>
</font> dogs have been put to death in this country TODAY <?php echo $date ?>.<br />
Don't buy - Don't breed - ADOPT! </b>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = <?=(int)((time()-$timestamp)/14.6);?>;
        function increment() {
            i++;
            document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = i;
        }
        setInterval('increment()', 10600);
    </script>
```

The code functions but, you can see I need help and I am borderlined clueless.
I had to use 14.6 seen above to get the result to get close but, not correct.

I would also like to display the running total for the year as well.

Can someone help me?

Thanks so much for the help but I cannot get it to function. Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> count up test </title>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var div = document.getElementById('count');
var yeardiv = document.getElementById('yearcount');

function updateCount() {
    var d = new Date();
    // set d to midnight
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var count = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 10600 );
    div.innerHTML = count;

    // set d to Jan 1st
    d.setMonth( 0 );
    d.setDate( 1 );
    count = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 10600 )
    yeardiv.innerHTML = count;
}

updateCount();
setInterval( updateCount, 10600 );


</script>


</head>
<body>
Today: <div id="count"></div><br/>
This Year: <div id="yearcount"></div>

</body>


</html>
```

The above does not show counts, just text...

**THANK YOU BELOW WORKS!!**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> count up test THANKS to agreco </title>
</head>
<body>

Today: <div id="count"></div><br/>
This Year: <div id="yearcount"></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var div = document.getElementById('count');
var yeardiv = document.getElementById('yearcount');

function updateCount() {
    var d = new Date();
    // set d to midnight
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var count = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 10600 );
    div.innerHTML = count;

    // set d to Jan 1st
    d.setMonth( 0 );
    d.setDate( 1 );
    count = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 10600 )
    yeardiv.innerHTML = count;
}

updateCount();
setInterval( updateCount, 10600 );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I really want to thank you for your help!

Comment: you'll have to wrap the code in `window.addEvent('load', function() { *code here* });` or place the script tag below the div elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to do it all in javascript.. As the other comment said, it will include the users timezone as well, where php would be based on the server time.

Here's the updated code for year as well:

```
var div = document.getElementById('count');
var yeardiv = document.getElementById('yearcount');

function updateCount() {
    var d = new Date();
    // set d to midnight
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var count = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 10600 );
    div.innerHTML = count;

    // set d to Jan 1st
    d.setMonth( 0 );
    d.setDate( 1 );
    count = Math.floor( ( new Date().getTime() - d.getTime() ) / 10600 )
    yeardiv.innerHTML = count;
}

updateCount();
setInterval( updateCount, 10600 );
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cx6rC/1/)

instead of incrementing, I just calculated the count based on *now* - *midnight*

Comment: Why not? Because I am clueless and over think everything! Also, I did not want to use onload in the body tag but, I may have to. What about the total for the year part though? I will try your answer and get back to you. Thanks so much! Huh, I can't get it to work although it seems to work at fiddle???

Comment: oops, missed the year part. Added year count [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cx6rC/1/) i'll update the answer with it

Comment: Your example works great at fiddle but, cannot get it to work in a page! I am really struggling here. I will place your code above in my question in attempt to discover what I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 1):

I'd skip PHP and do it just in JavaScript.  Use the JavaScript Date object, then calculate the number of seconds since midnight using hours minutes and seconds.  Your increment timer seems fine.  Plus, using JavaScript will use the viewer's timezone (JavaScript runs on browser) instead of the server's timezone (PHP runs on server).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're struggling to obtain the seconds from midnight in PHP, you can do it like so:

```
<?php 
$ar = explode(':',date('G:i:s'));
$ar[0] *= 3600;
$ar[1] *= 60;
$seconds_from_midnight = $ar[0] + $ar[1] + $ar[2];
$dogs_killed_from_midnight = floor($seconds_from_midnight / 10.6);
?>
```

and then just replace your following code:

```
<?=(int)((time()-$timestamp)/14.6);?>
```

for this:

```
<?=$dogs_killed_from_midnight;?>
```

that should do the job in your code.